# Updating state after async action in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

The general idea is that someone clicks the button, action fetches data from server and dispatches it. The state is updating and the content on the page is changing. The action looks exacly like that:

```
     export function getPosts(page){
     return function(dispatch){
      axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/home?page=${page}`)
          .then(response => {
            dispatch ({
            type: FETCH_POSTS,
            payload: response.data        
          })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          });
    }
    }
```

Reducer is pretty straightforward:

```
      export default function(state={}, action){
      switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_POSTS:
        return {posts: action.payload, ...state};
      }
      return state;
    }
```

And the main page is looking just like that:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import * as actions from '../actions';
    import RequireAuth from './auth/require_auth';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { compose } from 'redux';
    class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        posts: 'loading....',
      };
      this.props.getPosts();
    }  
    handlePage(){
    console.log(this.props);
    let page = 3;
    this.props.getPosts();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      let posts = nextProps.posts.posts.map((post) => {
      return (<li key={post._id}>{post.date}</li>)
      });
      this.setState({posts: posts});

    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextState, nextProps){
    console.log(nextProps.posts, nextState.posts);
    return true;
    }
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            {this.state.posts}
            <button onClick={this.handlePage.bind(this)}>change something</button>
          </div>
          )
    }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state){
      return {posts: state.post}
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Home);
```

I was thinking that the state will update in componentWillReciveProps but that is not happening. The data will be fetched after some time so i can't set state just like that. Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

for async actions, there are two possible ways:

1. an additional `status` flag
2. additional actions

The workflow would like:

1. Fetching data, dispatch an action, which sets `status` to `'fetching'`
2. if fetching is successfull, dispatch an action, which sets `status`to `'success'`
3. if fecthing fails, dispatch an action, which sets `status` to `'error'`

Further reading: [Redux :: Async actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#actions)

Comment: Thanks mate ! That works perfectly ! I can read about React all day long but I never liked Redux docs but for sure i will read them more often :)

Comment: glad that I could help :)